# Connecting MySQL workbench to MS ODBC

Tags: mysql, odbc, mysql-workbench

I am trying to connect a MySQL server i have made in SQL workbench to ODBC so that i can access the data in excel.

I have checked that my server and instance are running, I have also allowed ODBC through my windows firewall.

[image: server running]

I have tried entering 127.0.0.1, localhost and my full computer name as the TCP address however i still get a connection denied message.

[image: the connection window]

[image: Error Message]

However if i test the connection from within workbench it connects fine to the SQL Server.

[image: Connecting to the database from within workbench]

Answer (score 0):

Ok i found a way to make it work,

Navigate to "users and privileges" within SQL Workbench,

[image]

Select your username from the left (not root)

[image]

Then were it says "limit to host matching" change the "%" symbol to your local ip 127.0.0.1, Also change the root password.

[image]

Then enter these new details in ODBC and it should work.

[image]

Comment: That's an odd solution, given that the anyhost pattern `%` matches all IP addresses, including `localhost` and the loopback address (127.0.0.1). Maybe it was rather a wrong password that lead to the problem?

Comment: Mike Lischke, Hi im not sure as a tried a few passwords before changing the "%", I have no idea though im just glad it worked.